# Typescript | Open Excel file, Recalculate existing formula and Save it to local drive

Tags: excel, typescript

As part of UI automation, i need to upload an Excel file. However before doing so, I have to open an excel so that the exiting formulas such as =now() gets recalculated. And once its done need to save the excel file back.

I would like to know how using Typescript (and any node modules), i can automate the opening of excel, recalculation of the formulas and saving it back with same name and into same folder. For example: C:\Excel\UploadEmployeeDetails.xlsx

I tried my hand by using xlsx, excel-read-only packages.
By using them I was able to read the content and also to make it into JSON data etc. But my actual purpose of opening, recalculating and saving it back to local drive didn't materialize.